# Android - Good practice to keep/store loaded JSON

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-sqlite

I would like to make a news reader like the [The New York Times for Android](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nytimes.android&hl=en).

I parse a JSON file which conatains about 100 articles (title, content string, image url, ... etc.).

I would use ListFragment to show the list of the articles (title and image), and show the full content on a ViewPager so the reader can swipe across the articles.

So the Listfragment and the ViewPager would use the same article dataset.

What is the good practice to keep/store the downloaded articles?

I have some ideas:

- Keep the articles in a static ArrayList? (save the json file for
  offline reading)
- Create SQLite database and access with cursors? (Is it slow?)
- Create database, and at application start load all articles into a
  static ArrayList?
- Keep the ArrayList as a member variable of the Activity and passing
  the list to the fragments?

Thank you very much for your help! (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `SQLite` database, works enough fast. `JSON` file is also speed solution (depends how you will parse that file). **Don't** use static fields